# java.lang.NullPointerException on a local deployment only after file modification

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, web, local

Ok, this is strange. I have WAMP and Tomcat on a win7 workstation. I downloaded a copy of a live website, that is working fine. I also set up a copy of the db. Website is a very old jsp website.

Everything is fine when I work on the homepage. If I click on other pages, like "news", "features", I can see everything working perfectly.

But if I open the news.jsp, features.jsp... files, and I change even the smallest thing, or nothing at all, but I save them again, I get the nefarious     nullpointerexception error:

```
message java.lang.NullPointerException

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception`enter code here`

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.NullPointerException
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:584)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:395)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException
org.apache.jsp.Pages.features_jsp.jspDestroy(features_jsp.java:42)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.destroy(HttpJspBase.java:59)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.destroy(JspServletWrapper.java:477)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:165)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:368)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

What the heck is going on? How is it possible that the files work fine but if I open them they stop working? Is this a permission problem? I come from php and have no idea on how to deal with this environment.

Answer (score 1):

Have you automatically changed the **encoding** of file by saving? Check the old encoding and u can compare the size of former and latter files.

Have you automatically changed its **line break**? Some line break in windows doesn't perform well in Linux, as the well-known \n and \r\n problem. Besides, I once edited a bash file in Notepad++ in widows, but it has exception when executing it in Linux. Then the solution is re-typing it in Linux.

By the way, would you mind pasting the code of *jspDestroy(features_jsp.java:42)* and so on so I can have more information?

Hope it helps!

Comment: It's strange because even if I re-download the file from the live deployment, it still does not work.... O_o

Comment: Then it may because the property of system is changed.

Comment: What does this exactly mean? How can I fix it? I really have no clue on how to proceed this time.

Comment: Uhm. Where should it be? I can't find the file. But then again... how is it working online and not locally? I have everything that there is online.

Comment: Could this be a bad Tomcat configuration? Or the fact that the live server is older than the one I set up locally?

Comment: @AlessandroValentini Of course it may be. So why not first understand its all code, then you can make a new project, whose code is copied from the former?

Comment: This is an old company website. I need to make some quick changes in the layout but not rebuild the old thing, because that something that we are going to do later on with a completely different technology.

What I do not understand is why the Tomcat server return that error only sometimes. I can't even find those [name]_jsp.java files.

Comment: @AlessandroValentini If something is wrong with *the server*, try to create a new project, then copy *the content of* every file to the new project. If not work, try reinstall Tomcat and environment.